# formatting text/plain for printer

Tags: php, printing, cloud

I need to formatting text/plain  to add some margin, right, column , back to link  etc.....
my cloud printer accept text/plain as mediaType.
the printer accept also Star Document Markup, but i dont know how to use Star Document Markup in php code
NB :i am using php

````
            $mac = $request->getParam('mac');
            header('Content-Type: text/plain');

            // if (($job = $db->fetchRow("SELECT * FROM starcloud_jobs WHERE printer_mac = " . $db->quote($mac) . " ORDER BY checkout_id ASC")) && ($job['active'] == 0)) {
                $checkout = new Checkout();
                // $checkout->get($job['checkout_id']);
                $checkout_id = $checkout->get(17009);
                // $checkout_id = $checkout->get(17009);

                $restaurant = new Restaurant();
                $restaurant->get($checkout_id->restaurant_id);  
                $text = $restaurant->name.PHP_EOL;
                $text .= $restaurant_adresse->street1.PHP_EOL;
                $text .= $restaurant_adresse->mobile.PHP_EOL;
                $text .= $adresse->zipcode.' '.$adresse->postalname.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;

                $text .= "#" . $checkout->id. ' '. strtoupper($mode_livraison) . ' '.$checkout->getDeliveryTime(). ' ' . date('d/m/Y',$checkout->creation_date) .PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;


                $text .= 'MERCI POUR VOTRE COMMANDE!'. PHP_EOL;

                echo $text;exit();```

thanks in advance
````

Comment: Where is the problem? [Star Document Markup](https://www.star-m.jp/products/s_print/CloudPRNTSDK/Documentation/en/articles/markup/markupintro.html) found in 1 second.

Comment: @MarkusZeller   thanks for you replay, how can i use Star Document Markup in php code,  for formatting my  $text

Comment: Exactly that is in the provided link with an example of a bar code bill.

Comment: @markuszeller in my exemple  $text contain all the data to be printed, i use `PHP_EOL` to return to  a new line.  how can i use this  `[align: centre][font: a]\`  in my code. can you give me a concret exemple using `$text`  thanks

Comment: @MarkusZeller like this  :  `$text = "[align: centre][font: a]\";`   ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does anyone know about Star Document Markup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62026819/does-anyone-know-about-star-document-markup)

Comment: @markuszeller not yet